# Syntax highlight in Knowledge articles

Tags: knowledge

We are planning to move our current knowledge base to Salesforce Knowledge. One of the main concerns is that we have tons of sample code in different languages (C#, JavaScript, VB, Delphi) and it seems that SF Knowledge does not provide a built-in syntax highlight feature.

Does anyone know whether there is a way to add syntax highlight for code contained in a Salesforce Knowledge article?

Comment: An alternative could be to use images taken after code is syntax higlighted in sublime text or any other tool .

Comment: I know this isn't Ideal, but in cases like this we've had some success in just having using copy the formatted text form another program, and paste into a rich text field for the article.  Again, not ideal, but a possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using any built-in functionality of Salesforce knowledge, but you can use an external JavaScript syntax highlighter in conjunction with a Visualforce page to display the knowledge article.

I've integrated Alex Gorbatchev's Syntax Highlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) which produces the output shown below when I render an article containing code:

[image]

This is using the java brush - you may find you prefer one of the others.

I've written up how to achieve this in a blog post at:

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/syntax-highlighting-in-knowledge.html

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now native  after summer 14 release

[image]

There is a code sample button where one can add code

Comment: Great! But is the code is highlighted in correspondence to the code language?

Comment: No .As you can see its just Pre tab and wont be doing syntax highlighting as the below solution from BOb